# Nginx reverse proxy configuration for subdomain with multiple paths

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, sentry, grafana

I have a situation here with my Nginx reverse proxy configuration. My distribution is Ubuntu 14.04

I have a domain, let's call it foo.bar.net, and I want the /grafana endpoint to redirect to my grafana server (localhost:3000), the /sentry endpoint to redirect to my sentry server (localhost:9000) and finally, the /private endpoint to redirect to my django server (localhost:8001). I am using gunicorn for the tuneling between django and nginx.

Here is what I tried :

```
server {
    # listen on port 80
    listen 80 default_server;

    # for requests to these domains
    server_name foo.bar.net;

    location /sentry {
        # keep logs in these files
        access_log /var/log/nginx/sentry.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/sentry.error.log;

        # You need this to allow users to upload large files
        # See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size
        # I'm not sure where it goes, so I put it in twice. It works.
        client_max_body_size 0;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        allow   0.0.0.0;
        # make sure these HTTP headers are set properly
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /grafana {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        allow   0.0.0.0;
        # make sure these HTTP headers are set properly
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /private {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    location /private/static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/user/folder/private/static/;
    }
}
```

The server won't even start correctly, the config is not loading.

I would also like the / path to redirect to the private endpoint if possible.

Additionally, I am not even sure where to put this configuration (sites-available/??)

Can anyone help me with that ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing semicolons and other syntax errors. Look at main nginx error log for details and fix them one by one.

Where to put that config file depends on your distribution. For some of them it should be sites-available directory and symlink to that file inside sites-enabled directory for quick enabling and disabling sites, if you don't have sites-available and sites enabled directory, you should put it into conf.d dir in your distribution.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the configuration so there is no syntax error anymore. Still no luck though. My distrib is Ubuntu 14.04.